# How can I make a bootstrap input group only on tablet sized devices and above?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap 3 and am looking to have the following.

Tablet sized devices and above:

```
|    Input-text-area | button flush against the right edge of the text area    |
```

Mobile sized devices:

```
|        Input-text-area        |
|           button here         |
```

This is quite easy - using this : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons Great!

However, I only want this layout when on devices >=768 pixels width i.e anything greater than col-xs-12. When on a mobile I want the Button element to drop down onto the next line - center aligned. This is my existing code:

```html
<form id="signup-form" class="new_invitation" action="/invitations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-3 input-position">
    <input class="form-control full-width cinput" placeholder="Enter email address...   " id="InputEmail" type="text" name="invitation[recipient_email]">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 input-position fixit" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="JOIN IN" class="btn btn-default position-mobile cbigbtn" id="gabetabtn">
  </div>
</form>
```

This allows me to have my button on the right of my input text field on devices > XS and on its own centered col-xs-12 on mobile devices.

What CSS magic can I do to have this input text field become an input group which only groups flush to the input box on devices > 768 pixels wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like this, nesting bootstrap columns:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" style="padding:0px;">
        <input class="form-control full-width cinput" placeholder="Enter email address...   " id="InputEmail" type="text" name="invitation[recipient_email]">    
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3" style="padding:0px;">
        <span class="input-group-btn" style="margin:0 auto;">
          <input type="submit" name="commit" value="JOIN IN" class="btn btn-default position-mobile cbigbtn" id="gabetabtn" style="width:100%;">
        </span>      
      </div>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Your other option would be to look at media queries and add those to your css document.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: This is great - how can i force my input box to be  width:357px; on tablets and devices larger, and full width on mobile? - https://jsfiddle.net/myfmLdpc/1/

Comment: I'm having a problem with the class specificity, but you'll want to use a media query for this .size{
  width:357px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .size{
    width:100%;
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

These are all the rules that you need to change in order to acheive the desired behavior and so the button and input remain aligned under 768px.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .new_invitation .input-group .form-control,
  .new_invitation .input-group-btn {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .new_invitation .input-group-btn .btn {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .new_invitation .input-group-btn > .btn + .btn {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .new_invitation .input-group-btn:first-child > .btn {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  .new_invitation .input-group-btn:last-child > .btn {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .new_invitation .input-group {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">

      <form id="signup-form" class="new_invitation" action="/invitations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control full-width cinput" placeholder="Enter email address..." id="InputEmail" type="text" name="invitation[recipient_email]">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="JOIN IN" class="btn btn-default position-mobile cbigbtn" id="gabetabtn">
      </span>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with bootstrap classes only, without modifying CSS?